# T-SQL >> operator like in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Could you help me with the issue - I need to implement `>>` operator in `T-SQL` like in `C#`. How to make it ?

Comment: @PaulG T-SQL, MS SQL Server

Comment: It's probably best not to. Bit manipulation (and data that *requires* bit manipulation) don't really belong in a relational database.

Comment: You cannot introduce new operators, but you can implement the functionality of `X >> Y` by dividing `X / Power(2, Y)`, for `X << Y` do multiply instead of divide.

Comment: Do you really need to shift or are you trying to access specific bits? [This](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/bitmask-handling-part-4-left-shift-and-right-shift.aspx) blog may be of use for shifting. Accessing specific bits is better handled by masking, at least in TSQL. For more approaches to shifting you can use your favorite search engine to find `t sql bit shift`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i can replace `>>` operator logic with division and multiplication on multiple number.